# Custom Post type content not displaying on single page

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I have added a select dropdown on my custom post type in the admin panel. Basically that is a select dropdown that is displaying my other custom post type title. I used the below code.

```
$args = array( 'post_type'=>'blogauthor','post_status' => 'publish' );
    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts($args);
    $getblogauthorId=get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'blogauthor', true );// get selected when hit URL page
    echo '<select name="blogauthor">
            <option  value="" selected="" disabled="">Select Author</option>';
    foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
        if($recent["ID"]==$getblogauthorId){ $authselected='selected="selected"';};
        echo'<option value="' .$recent["ID"].'" '.$authselected.'>' .   $recent["post_title"].'</option> ';
    }
echo'</select>';
```

There is no issue with the above dropdown.

Now I am on a single page and I have to show the content which I selected from the dropdown.
what is the issue with the below code because every time it's run else part.
If I remove `'meta_key' => 'blogauthor', 'meta_value' => $blogauthorId,` then I am getting all the post but I have to show that post which id is with `meta_value`.

```
$blogauthorId=get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'blogauthor', true );
        $the_query =array(
          'post_type'              => array( 'blogauthor' ),
          'post_status'            => array( 'publish' ),
          'meta_query'             => array(
                               array(
                             'key'       => 'blogauthor',
                             'value'     => $blogauthorId
                            )
                           ),
      'order'      => 'DESC'
    );
        $authorData = new WP_Query($the_query);
        if ($authorData->have_posts()): while($authorData->have_posts()): $authorData->the_post();
        echo"<pre>";
        //var_dump(get_the_content());
        var_dump(get_the_content($authorData->ID));
        endwhile; else:
        echo "Please select author";

        endif;
```

I the query `echo"<pre>"; print_r($the_query);` and I got below output which is correct

```
Array
(
    [post_type] => Array
        (
            [0] => blogauthor
        )

    [post_status] => Array
        (
            [0] => publish
        )

    [meta_query] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [key] => blogauthor
                    [value] => 191
                )

        )

    [order] => DESC
)
```

Comment: I tried  'meta_query'             => array(
        array(
            'key'       => 'blogauthor',
            'value'     => $blogauthorId,
        ), but still same issue

Comment: Are you sure `get_post_meta` is actually returning the expected value (or any value at all) for `$blogauthorId`? Have you tried printing it out to see what it is returning?

Comment: @FluffyKitten, Is there any issue with that code? Because I print $blogauthorId and I got 192 which is correct.

Comment: use 
echo '<pre>';
print_r($authorData);
echo '</pre>';
for getting it's inside

Comment: be confirm that your query is returning objects

Comment: Hard to say when we don't know your setup or being able to try it. You do have some unnecessary code such as the `order` arg. You'll have to try debug it to see what might be happening. Does it work if you minimise the args being used and if you hardcode the value for `$blogauthorId` into the args array, for example.

Comment: @FluffyKitten, I updated my args in the question with output.

Comment: @ArifulIslam, I added  echo '<pre>'; print_r($authorData); echo '</pre>'; inside while loop but nothing is displaying

Comment: That's a different query than what you had - you didn't have a `meta_query`. Also, did you try removing the unnecessary args as I suggested?

Comment: now add this line  '<pre>'; print_r($authorData->get_posts()); echo '</pre>'; $authorData = new WP_Query($the_query); and check what it's inside?

Comment: @FluffyKitten, Yes, I removed order args from my query.

Comment: @ArifulIslam, your last comment is correct? because of how it will call $authorData?

Comment: @ArifulIslam, I added  '<pre>'; print_r($authorData->get_posts()); echo '</pre>';  after WP_Query and I am getting the WP_Query Object (// lot's of array)

Comment: now add this line '<pre>'; print_r($authorData->get_posts()); echo '</pre>'; after $authorData = new WP_Query($the_query); and check what it's inside? spelling mistake. Check it.

Comment: And can you loop through that array?

Comment: @ArifulIslam, Output  https://prnt.sc/up31rk https://prnt.sc/up31z8 https://prnt.sc/up32h0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222164/discussion-between-ariful-islam-and-user9437856).

Comment: O ho your array is empty. Check your arguments that you are passing for Wp_Query. it is right or not.

Comment: @ArifulIslam,  I have to match the POST ID with the meta_query value ID If match then displays the content.

Comment: Print_r everytime after arguments changing and commeting.

Comment: @ArifulIslam, I don't think so there is some issue in the if and while condition because that is working when I comment meta_query.

Comment: I think meta query is not right.

Comment: Finally, I found my solution, I deleted all the code and added only 
$blogauthorId=get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'blogauthor', true );
$singlepost = get_post($blogauthorId); 
echo $title = $singlepost->post_title;
echo $content = $singlepost->post_content;

Comment: It's displaying what I am looking for. Now I just want to pass post_type like $the_query =array(
     'post_type'              => 'blogauthor',
     'post_status'            => 'publish',
    );